# Uploading to Github

Tags: git, github

I have a project which uses AJAX to get information from an API. I have it hosted on my local wamp server and I want to post the project online using Git. **(I'm trying to create a GitHub Page)** How can I do this? I've tried but usually I get a 404 error: "The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file"

This is my process:

1. Create a repo on github.com
2. git init
3. git add * to add all the files
4. git status to check which files are untracked
5. git commit -m “first commit”
6. git remote add origin (https://github.com/username/repo.git)
7. git checkout -b gh-pages to create github page
8. git push orign gh-pages

This usually works for all of my projects. I'm aware that I may need different type of command or to do something different with the files. I'm just not sure what, since I'm new to Version Control.

Thanks.

Comment: First:  *what* error?  Second:  are you just trying to create a GitHub page?

Comment: What is that "github page" for? Just leave it away. Also do not try to create a branch (-b). This is your first commit. You want to commit to stable, not to some branch. Did you read the short introduction github offers for beginners? Read it, it is worth it!

Comment: @arkascha — I think the question is asking how to use the [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) feature to host a site that makes use of Ajax. That makes creating the gh-pages branch pretty essential.

Comment: @Quentin might be, but the OP said nothing about that. All that is said is "I want to post the project online using Git". Nothing about github pages and interacting with 'em. I'd say a classical question that need more details from the OP. Let's see...

Comment: Have you tried the GitHub forums??

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is in your origin path. Once a repo is created, look for this box on the right side:

[image: Clone URL]

That's your origin url, which is formatted:

```
https://github.com/<userNeme>/<projectName>.git
```

so use that URL in your `git remote add origin` statement.

A second practice, even better in my opinion, is after creating the repo, clone the empty repo (using `git clone https://github.com/<userNeme>/<projectName>.git`), and commit your changes there. This takes care for you having your local repo all set up.

Comment: Isn't that what I did on step 6 ? Doesn't the "git remote add origin" part take care of cloning the repo ?

Comment: Not at all. What you did is add the remote server as a remote for your local repo, but you never cloned the remote one.

I suggest you `cd` to an empty directory and `git clone`. That will be an actual clone of you GitHub repo.

Comment: @NitaiJ.Perez Sorry, but disagree. What OP did is perfectly fine. The only thing missing is actually setting the upstream, but the push attempt should tell them about that. In fact, this flow of setting up a new repo is the way Github suggests you to do it when creating a new repo.

Comment: Thanks, what you're saying makes sense. However, it doesn't seem to work. I feel that it may have something to do with the fact that I'm using a local server ?

Comment: @IngoBürk, you are totally correct. I just explained that adding a remote is not cloning *per se*.

Comment: @FNunez, I don't think that's the reason. Are your pushes going through okay?

Comment: @NitaiJ.Perez  Yes it seems they are. I get a message that says "Everything-up-to-date" in the terminal when I push. The files are also inside the repository on Github. But the page isn't up.